# Как правильно указать ID при сборке notification?

Tags: java, android

Когда мы используем `notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build())`, то как указано в документации `NOTIFICATION_ID` должен быть уникальным так как если есть приложение с таким же ид то будет показываться более свежее уведомление. Я вот хотел узнать как на практике присваивают этот ид чтоб он с большей вероятностью получился уникальный? Я вот думаю можно попробовать что то вроде этого `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` но не уверен, что это выглядит красиво...

Answer (score 3):

В кой-то веки интересный вопрос)

Вот вам в помощь: https://github.com/sanathe06/AndroidGuide/blob/master/ExampleCompatNotificationBuilder/src/com/android/guide/compatnotificationbuilder/MainActivity.java

P.s тут этот вопрос был уже обсужден: http://ru.androids.help/q2525

Comment: Старайтесь писать развернутые ответы. В ответе должно содержаться полностью рабочее решение, а не ссылки. Ссылки можно добавить в качестве дополнительной информации

Comment: Я так понял, что я могу использовать `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` так как в целом это одно и то же... Или я что то упустил?

Comment: в целом это одно и то же так что можете)

Answer (score 0):

Мною проверено, что `Notifications` из разных приложений могут вполне себе иметь одинаковый `id` и не замещать друг друга. Так что вам нужно думать лишь о том, чтобы `id` не повторялось в рамках одного приложения (если не хотите замещения), что гораздо проще. 
Можно, например, просто инкрементировать предыдущее значение, сохраняя его где-то между запусками приложения.